# How can i publish my Lighning survey

Tags: publisher, salesforce-survey

Hello friends firstly you know in salesforce you should create Surveys this is so simple way this is good yes but i cant publishing "Participants Outside Your Company"

This image system gave link to for outside, but!
First image: https://pasteboard.co/Irh2DPu.png
edit:
[image]

When i send my link to other users they cant see, /404

https://pasteboard.co/Irh4FJL.png
edit:
[image]

Comment: Could you please upload your screenshots using the Insert Image button in the editor so that they may be shown inline in your question?

Comment: Sure i'ill upload now